# Subtract rows from one another, but skip strings

Tags: excel, vba

I know I can subtract entire rows with the following line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A20:G20") = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Evaluate("A2:G2-A10:G10")
```

However, I have strings in a few columns. I tried hiding those columns, but this doesn't make Excel skip them. In theory I could delete them and re-insert them afterwards, but if possible I'd like to avoid a solution with so many steps in between.

I'm working with two workbooks and about 2500 rows and 20 columns.

Comment: What is the issue? If you do that with strings the result woud obviosly be `#VALUE!`. What would you expect how Excel would handle your strings?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I want Excel to skip those columns so that the original string remains unaffected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then test with `=IFERROR` if the result of your subtraction returns `#VALUE!` and in that case return the original value:

```
.Evaluate("=IFERROR(A2:G2-A10:G10,A2:G2)")
```

This returns the value from A2:G2 if the subtraction errors.

Alternatively you can also check for numbers:

```
.Evaluate("=IF(ISNUMBER(A2:G2),A2:G2-A10:G10,A2:G2)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use code like below:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A20:G20")
    .Formula = "=IFERROR(A2-A10,"""")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```